# execl function in Linux c

Tags: c, linux, exec

I'm started Linux internal concept. In the following program, **why isn't the second `printf` executed?**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Before execl");
  execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
  printf("After execl");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `printf` is not executed because `execl` takes over your application's process and replaces it with the new specified process. Per the man pages:

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. The functions described in this manual page are front-ends for execve(2). (See the manual page for execve(2) for further details about the replacement of the current process image.)

And from the `execve(2)` man page:

> execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program loaded. If the current program is being ptraced, a SIGTRAP is sent to it after a successful execve().

If you want your program to continue execution and display the second `printf`, you'll have to call `execl` (or any functions in the `exec` family) inside a `fork` child. The C standard library function `system()` does just this, and you can view the source code [here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/procexec/system.c.html).